# Is composer available as a set of PHP scripts?

Tags: php, composer-php, phar

I haven't found any way of installing composer on my shared hosting. I don't understand the insistence of using a phar, surely composer could comfortably be ported to plain PHP scripts? Is there such a port? Or a way of achieving the same?

Comment: Why don't you simply download the .phar and unpack it if you absolutely insist on plain files?

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea that was possible; I was convinced phar's were compiled libraries!

Comment: Alternatively, build the project locally with a PHP install and just upload everything to your host.

Comment: The problem is I use git to deploy, and I don't check in the vendor directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `phar` file is a PHP archive. So download the composer file locally and upload them to your server. You need only a PHP-Interpreter installed on your CLI.

Then you can run them `php composer.phar` or without PHP if your host is correctly configured.

http://php.net/manual/de/phar.using.intro.php

https://getcomposer.org/download/

Normally you can install composer with the given command on the composer site.

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```